# Flex Card Slider

Tags: flexbox, slider, card

I need a code for flex card slider using html/css please check the slide in the [link](https://webflow.com/made-in-webflow/website/Skillex-Online-Education) for reference. I tried the following code but it shows the right side picture the biggest but I want the left side picture which is the first picture the biggest of all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .card-slider {
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .card {
      width: 100px; /* Set your initial width /
      transition: width 0.3s ease; / Add transition for smooth effect /
    }

    .card:hover {
      width: 150px; / Set the width you want on hover */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card-slider">
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Your card content goes here -->
    <img src="image_1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Your card content goes here -->
    <img src="image_2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Your card content goes here -->
    <img src="image_2.jpg" alt="Image 3">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```